Saved Search with Paycheck Payment Method
I'm trying to write a saved search that shows expense reports and their payment status through Paying Transaction fields.  These expense reports are paid by either Bill Payment or Paycheck.  So far so good.
I want to show the Payment Method for paychecks to indicate if paid by Direct Deposit or Service Printed Check, but I can't find the field.  Is there any way to access this field?
Paycheck Transaction Showing Payment Method Field

Saved Search Criteria

Saved Search Results


I would recommend using Analytics here. I believe you can easily find the Payment Method tab here.
You can follow the below steps -

Go to 'Analytics' tab and create a new workbook.

Next, you will get an option to create a new dataset. Create it.

Here, you are required to create a dataset. In the 'Search Record Types', select 'Transaction' and in here, you can add all the desired columns. If you search for 'Payment Method' in the 'Search by Name or ID' tab, you will find it. Note that there would be many 'Payment Method' fields available from various different transactions. You will either need to select the appropiate one or just select all and check for the appropiate one. Also make sure to add main line field. You can filter it in workbook.


Save the dataset and create the workbook. Select type as Table. You can now add filters here and get the data as per the requirement.


You should be good to go. This analytics tab can be used via UI and can also be used in Suitescripts. Similar to Saved Searches.


I guess you should be good to go here. Let me know if you require any detailed step or in case of any questions.
Edit -
You can add the workbook to your NetSuite dashboard using the Analytics Portlet. See the screenshot below.


Thanks for the response @Sayeesh .  That was very helpful.  I found the field in Analytics by searching for "Use Direct Deposit".  It's called 'Entity (Employee)' > 'Use Direct Deposit'.  Is there anyway to access the dataset from a saved search, or to setup an alert based on dataset results, or to show the results on a dashboard?  We are trying to alert Payroll if an employee is setup for direct deposit but is paid with a "Service Printed Check".

Hey @ChrisB , you can add the workbook to the dashboard by personalizing the dashboard. Check the screenshot above in the answer.

Hey @Sayeesh , I wanted an alert to appear before committing a payroll batch, allowing a chance to change the payment method if needed. Looks like that’s not fully possible yet. +1 for getting me 90% there!
